# NSScrollView disable autoscrolling

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscrollview

How do I disable the autoscroll in a `NSScrollView` as I'm filling it with content?

I have subclassed it in my own class but I don't find an appropriate method to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably more than one way to go about this, but take a look at `-[NSClipView constrainScrollPoint:]`. It's not meant to be called directly, rather to be overridden in an `NSClipView` subclass. `NSClipView` is the class that actually does the real work of scrolling the content of an `NSScrollView`.

You should be able to override it to simply return the document view's current origin point when you don't want scrolling to happen. It's worth noting that this will also disable scrolling via the user-visible interface, so you should only do it while you're filling the view with content. Otherwise, return the result of a call to the superclass's implementation.

Comment: I did what you tell me, but when I'm replacing the `[NSScrollView contentView]` it seems that it is not getting replaced. I'm replacing it by extending my `NSScrollView` and overriding `- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect;`.

Comment: If you set the scrollview up in Interface Builder, you should be able to use your custom NSClipView subclass by setting its class in IB. To do it programmatically, you should be able to use -[NSScrollView setContentView:] passing in an instance of your custom clip view subclass. You'll need to make sure that you also set the document view correctly.

Comment: This worked for me at once. Just returning `self.bounds`.